# How can I create a Sub Query from the same table - SQL Developer

Tags: java, sql, database

I'm new to SQL queries and DB functionality in general. I'm trying to create a single query so I can get some info sorted, something like this:

```
LVL     PRODUCT          DESCRIPTION
5       01AR2TGELL       DESLVL5
6       01AR2TGELLGS     DESLVL6
7       01AR2TGELLGSQKA  DESLVL7
6       01AR2TGELLDE     DESLVL6
7       01AR2TGELLDEUDP  DESLVL7
7       01AR2TGELLDEUZN  DESLVL7

With this table i want to get this approach:

LVL   PRODUCT          DESCRIPTION  | LVL   PRODUCT        DESCRIPTION  | LVL  PRODUCT     DESCRIPTION
7     01AR2TGELLGSQKA  DESLVL7      | 6     01AR2TGELLGS   DESLVL6      | 5    01AR2TGELL  DESLVL5
7     01AR2TGELLDEUDP  DESLVL7      | 6     01AR2TGELLDE   DESLVL6      | 5    01AR2TGELL  DESLVL5
7     01AR2TGELLDEUZN  DESLVL7      | 6     01AR2TGELLDE   DESLVL6      | 5    01AR2TGELL  DESLVL5
```

The table consists of approx. 65 Thousands entries like the first table.

I don't have much code done in SQL, what I did was to get all the LVL 7 entries:
`select * from PRODHIERARCHY where LVL=7`
Save them on an ArrayList in Java (Takes 3 minutes for 35 thousand entries approx.)

Then get the entries from LVL6, LVL5 until LVL1 and compare them to then print a table like the second one, but every LVL compared takes almost 20 minutes which is very inefficient.

I've been researching about subqueries but I couldn't get it. I don't really know if it would be easier to make many call queries in Java (Which I couldn't do too because I did not know how to compare the values in SQL) instead of one query.

P.D. I'm using Oracle SQL Developer if that modifies anything...

Any help would be much appreciated! Thanks!

Comment: Read up on PIVOT

Comment: If it’s taking 3 mins for 35000 entries you should check if the table has index on LVL column. If not, add one and try.

Comment: I agree with @SunilDabburi, you have an index in that table?

Comment: Maybe I'm missing something here, but couldn't this be as simple as just adding an index on `LVL` as suggested above and querying them out by level or ordered with an `ORDER BY` clause in your JDBC code? Is it a requirement to have a super wide output? What are you trying to do with this output?

Comment: No, I don't have an index column, I thought about it too but for what I understood the input will always be like that and cannot be modified. I don´t really know if the wide output is necessary. The main objective here is to read all the input and sort it, depending on all the LVL7, the PRODUCT shoould have a LVL6, LVL5, to LVL1. Only LVL7 - PRODUCT are unique and comparing the values or making a substring (I don't really know how to) I need to get the description for all levels.